# Plot with cube root in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to use only the tikz and pgfplots package to graph the function `$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{(x^{3}-x^{2})}$`.  How should I proceed? Does the code below not compile?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[domain=-2:2, samples=100] plot(\x, {(\x^(3)-\x^(2))^(1/3)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is an overleaf link with the error we observed: [Click Here!](https://www.overleaf.com/3342568827zmdygrtngwky)

Comment: This code doesn't plot the cube root, but the square of *x³–x²*.

Comment: @Bernard In fact, I was wrong to enter the code. I already made the correction! I apologize!

Comment: Don't be sorry. This kind of errors happen to all of us from time to time.

Comment: BTW `(x*x-x)*x` is faster and more accurate than `x^3-x^2`.  Try to avoid using `^` when computing.  It should be noted that `y^3=x` has three possible solutions. generally one real and two complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it! I used the fact that $x^(1/3)=(x/abs(x))*(abs(x))^(1/3)$. In that case, it compiled perfectly!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[domain=-2:2, samples=100, blue] plot(\x, {((((\x)^(3)-(\x)^(2)))/(abs(((\x)^(3)-(\x)^(2)))))*(abs(((\x)^(3)-(\x)^(2))))^(1/3)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to everyone who helped! We will keep good options here!

Comment: I have just checked pgfmanual. There is function `sign(x)`, so you can write `sign(f(\x))*pow(abs(f(\x)),1/3)` in this case.

Answer (score 8):

A `pstricks` solution:

```
\documentclass[svgnames, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2cm, algebraic, arrowinset=0.12, arrowsize=3pt, linejoin=1, showorigin=false}

\begin{pspicture*}(-2.6,-2.6)(2.6,2.6)
\psaxes[linecolor=LightSteelBlue, tickcolor=LightSteelBlue, arrows =->, ticksize=2pt -2pt, labelFontSize=\scriptstyle](0,0)(-2.6,-2.6)(2.6,2.6)[$x$,-135] [$y$,-135]
\uput[dl](0,0){$O$}
\psset{linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=IndianRed, plotpoints=200, plotstyle=curve}
\psplot{-2.6}{1}{-(x^2-x^3)^(1/3)}%
\psplot{1}{2.6}{(x^3-x^2)^(1/3)}%
\psline[linewidth=0.6pt, linecolor=Crimson!50](-2.8,-3.133)(2.8,2.467)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bernard, it was great. Thank you! However, this is a graphic for a project where we wanted to use only tikz, pgfplots and some of their libraries.

Comment: I understand. Yet, many things are simpler to do with pstricks.

Comment: If it doesn't work with tikz and pgfplots, we really have to go for pstricks. Thank you for your help and availability!

Comment: I think it should work, but unfortunately, I don't know tikz well enough to help.

Comment: Got it, but I appreciate your help anyway!

Answer (score 6):

Here are two Asymptote solutions for comparison with TikZ or pgfplots incoming answers as you are expected.

1. Asymptote has built-in cubic root function, so just go straight with it

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
import graph;
real f(real x) {return cbrt(x^3-x^2);} //<<< the cubic root function
path g = graph(f,-2,2,n=1000,operator --); // operator .. is not good around (0,0)
draw(g,red);
axes("$x$","$y$");
```

2. Asymptote has `contour` module for graphs of implicit function.

[image]

```
unitsize(1cm);
import contour;
import graph;
real F(real x, real y) { return x^3 - x^2 -y^3; }
guide[][] g = contour(F,a=(-2,-2), b=(2,2), new real[] {0});
draw(g[0],magenta);
axes("$x$","$y$");
```

**Update** Using TikZ with `sign` function.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=\x*\x*\x-\x*\x;}]
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[below right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[below left]{$y$};
\draw[orange,thick] plot[domain=-2:3,samples=300] (\x,{sign(f(\x))*pow(abs(f(\x)),1/3)}) 
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My bad and tricky code: In trying to use TikZ, I have to use a trick to get rid off negative base in power function, and joining pieces of the graph in different domains.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[samples=100,smooth,
declare function={f(\x)=\x*\x*\x-\x*\x;}
]
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[below right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[below left]{$y$};
\draw[orange,thick]
plot[domain=-2:1] (\x,{-pow(-f(\x),1/3)})--(1,0)--
plot[domain=1:3] (\x,{pow(f(\x),1/3)}) 
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but we are trying to build a report for building graphs in LATEX using only the tikz and pgfplots packages. So we ask for help!

Comment: Your piece of code unfortunately is no MWE. What tikzlibraries do you use? What error messages do you get?

Comment: @fsbmat see my update with TikZ. Tricky ^^

Comment: Hi @BlackMild I did. Am I evaluating why you use $-f (x)$ and $yscale = -1$?

Comment: @fsbmat `yscale=-1` is for reflecting to x-axis. I did that because `pow(a,b)` only works for positive value of `a`

Comment: @fsbmat I correct my code a bit. Now without `yscale`: `\draw[orange,thick]
plot[domain=-2:1] 
 (\x,{-pow(-f(\x),1/3)})--(1,0)--
plot[domain=1:3] (\x,{pow(f(\x),1/3)}) 
;
`