# Draw with fifth root in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pstricks

I'm trying to graph the following function: `y=\sqrt[5]{4x^4-x^5}` didn't work out the first time, so I searched here for something that might help me and found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/582721/248335). Unfortunately, when I edited the code, it didn't work out for me, so I would ask if there is a way to generally graph a root function?

```
\documentclass[svgnames, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2cm, algebraic, arrowinset=0.12, arrowsize=3pt, linejoin=1, showorigin=false}

\begin{pspicture*}(-2.6,-2.6)(2.6,2.6)
\psaxes[linecolor=LightSteelBlue, tickcolor=LightSteelBlue, arrows =->, ticksize=2pt -2pt, labelFontSize=\scriptstyle](0,0)(-2.6,-2.6)(2.6,2.6)[$x$,-135] [$y$,-135]
\uput[dl](0,0){$O$}
\psset{linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=IndianRed, plotpoints=200, plotstyle=curve}
\psplot{-2.6}{1}{-(x^5-4*x^4)^(1/5)}%
\psplot{1}{2.6}{(4*x^4-x^5)^(1/5)}%
\psline[linewidth=0.6pt, linecolor=Crimson!50](-2.8,-3.133)(2.8,2.467)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

**Output: by Geogebra**

[image]

Comment: The question asks for a tikz code, but your example is a pspicture. Which of those do you want to be used by the answer?

Answer (score 8):

This is an attempt to answer the question, based on the assumptions that

1. you want a tikz (rather than pstricks or pgfplots) code, and
2. you wish to keep the elements of the pspicture.

A possible code accomplishing this is

```
\documentclass[tikz,svgnames, border=3pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,line cap=round]
    \draw[->,LightSteelBlue] (-2.6,0) -- (2.6,0) node[below left]{$x$};
    \draw[->,LightSteelBlue] (0,-2.6) -- (0,2.6) node[below left]{$y$};
    \draw[line width=1.2pt,smooth,samples at={-2.6,-2.5,...,-0.1,-0.05,-0.01,0,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.2,...,2.6}] plot (\x,{\fpeval{(4*(\x)^4-(\x)^5)^(1/5)}});
    \draw[line width=0.6pt,Crimson!50](-2.8,-3.133)--(2.8,2.467);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that

- `\fpeval` is used since the basic pgf math is not too accurate when computing the root of a very small number,
- in older TeX installations you will need to load `xfp`, and
- `samples at` is employed to increase the density of samples around the origin.

Comment: when you employ `samples at` you not need to define `domain` (which is in your answer also wrong). `smooth` option is not needed (necessary) since you have sufficient number of sample that curve is smooth.

Comment: @Zarko First point: agree and fixed it, thanks! Second point: I disagree. There is a difference between having straight segments and Bezier curves. `smooth` can give bad results when used incorrectly, but this is precisely the reason why I use `samples at`.

Comment: In your case `smooth˙ (by use of the spline function) only overwhelmed compilation.  Result of compilation is not visible better. But this is up to you.

Comment: @Zarko Many of those who has used piecewise linear plots on a projector are glad that there is a smooth option. This is particularly true if one uses blowups such as `\framezoom` or `spy`. It also does not affect the computation time notably on a modern computer, let alone overwhelms it.

Comment: I will not argue with you. BTW, , I'm well aware what `smooth` functions do. It is not general cure, it may cause wrong result in drawed functions too...

Comment: Interesting, thank you very much for your answer, would it be possible for you to show me the different ways of plotting this with both tikz, pstricks or pgfplots? I am a beginner in this and I would like to see the different ways to make this graph and choose the one that seems most natural and understandable to me. Thanks in advance.

I will attach an image made in Geogebra as a reference of the result and the domain that interests me.

Answer (score 7):

run with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2cm, algebraic, arrowinset=0.12, arrowsize=3pt, linejoin=1, showorigin=false}   
\begin{pspicture}(-2.6,-2.6)(4.75,2.6)
    \psaxes[linecolor=LightSteelBlue, tickcolor=LightSteelBlue, arrows =->, ticksize=2pt -2pt, labelFontSize=\scriptstyle](0,0)(-2.6,-2.6)(4.5,2.6)[$x$,-135] [$y$,-135]
    \uput[dl](0,0){$O$}
    \psset{linewidth=2pt, linecolor=IndianRed, plotpoints=1200, plotstyle=line}
    \psplot{-2}{4}{(4*x^4-x^5)^(0.2)}%
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{4}{4.5}{-(abs(4*x^4-x^5))^(0.2)}%
    \psline[linewidth=0.6pt, linecolor=Crimson!50](-2.8,-3.133)(2.8,2.467)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I enlarge the domain, I find an error in `\psplot{-2}{5}{(4*x^4-x^5)^(0.2)}%`, how can I fix it?

Comment: it is your plot style! Use `line` instead of `curve` and more plot points

Answer (score 2):

You've come to a point where you are seeing some of the limitations of mathematics in LaTeX. To be fair, LaTeX is for typesetting and you shouldn't expect it to take the place of Geogebra. This is an opportunity to assess how much complicated mathematics you will be using in LaTeX
otherwise the problem of graphing the 5th root today can become [pgfplots: problem with convergence of addplot on (sin(x) - x cos(x)) / x^3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634038/pgfplots-problem-with-convergence-of-addplot-on-sinx-x-cosx-x3). As I say in my answer there, "The sledgehammer that will solve most any problem is a computer algebra system (CAS). The `sagetex` package gives you access to an open source CAS called [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) as well as Python programming.". A CAS has a steeper learning curve but can solve more problems: integration, derivatives, differential equations, matrix inverses, graph theory, etc. and Python gives you a powerful programming language to replace some of the more dated LaTeX programming that many here have mastered.

Here is a `sagetex` solution to your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex,xcolor,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
LowerX = -5
UpperX = 5
LowerY = -5
UpperY = 5
step = .01
t = var('t')
g(t)= real_nth_root(4*t^4-t^5, 5)

x_coords = [t for t in srange(LowerX,UpperX,step)]
y_coords = [g(t).n(digits=6) for t in srange(LowerX,UpperX,step)]

output = r""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]"
output += r"\begin{axis}[xmin=%f,xmax=%f,ymin= %f,ymax=%f,width=10cm,"%(LowerX,UpperX,LowerY, UpperY)
output += r"xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,axis x line=middle,axis y line=middle]"
output += r"\addplot[thin, blue, unbounded coords=jump] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(x_coords)-1):
    if (y_coords[i])<LowerY or (y_coords[i])>UpperY:
        output += r"(%f , inf) "%(x_coords[i])
    else:
        output += r"(%f , %f) "%(x_coords[i],y_coords[i])
output += r"};"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

The output in Cocalc is:

[image]

A brief explanation:
`sagesilent` environment is work behind the scenes that doesn't get printed until you tell it. `LowerX = -5, UpperX = 5, LowerY = -5, UpperY=5` sets up the parameters of what will be on the screen, `step = .01` sets up the spacing between x-values. `g(t)= real_nth_root(4*t^4-t^5, 5)` indicates the 5th root of your function will be graphed but since there are 5 such roots over the complex number field, we specify that the real valued answer will be used. `x_coords = [t for t in srange(LowerX,UpperX,step)]` creates a list of the specific x-coordinates that will be used: -5, -4.99, -4.98, ..., 4.99 (Python doesn't include the last number. You can modify to UpperX+step to go to 5.00). The y-coordinates get calculated using 6 significant digits. The picture is created as a text string because `sagetex` runs as a 3-step compilation process. If you search this site for `sagetex` you can find more explanation on this. `\sagestr{output}` takes the work created in `sagesilent` so that on the third step of compilation all the calculations/details from Python/Sage get typeset. The for-loop `for i in range(0,len(x_coords)-1):` checks that the y-value is on the screen. If it isn't the y-value is infinity and won't be plotted. Otherwise it will be plotted.

LaTeX, a CAS, and Python programming can help you solve and typeset most anything. However, the CAS Sage is not part of your distribution. The easiest way to access it is through a free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account. It's also possible to download Sage to your computer and get it to work with your LaTeX distribution. That takes more time and can be more problematic. It requires more maintenance as well: as Sage and LaTeX update on different schedules, that coordination can break. Working on Cocalc means they make sure everything stays up to date and works. If you don't need the mathematical power of a CAS then other solutions, such as `lua`, are probably more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it helps me a lot!